# How to access Azure SQL database with a Connection String in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

[image]

I can log into the server explorer to work on my database.
Yet I fail to access it with a Connection String.

Comment: Hello, can you accept my answer, please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

is your connection string in the format of `Server=tcp:{server}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={databaseName};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;`

- double check the password and firewall for your IP

Answer (score 0):

This is **ADO.NET** Connection String that I use for my Azure SQL C# project:

```
Server=tcp:YOUR_SERVER,1433;
Initial Catalog=YOUR_DB_NAMR;
Persist Security Info=False;
User ID=YOUR_LOGIN;Password=YOUR_PASSWORD};
MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
Encrypt=True;
TrustServerCertificate=False;
Connection Timeout=30;
```

And as @Krunal mentioned, double check your *login credentials*
and make sure your *IP* is whitelisted on the server side.

You can set a *0.0.0.0 to 250.250.250.250 range* as a whitelisted range, for testing purposes.